# I receive {"error":"Invalid request"} When trying to run .exe for a scripted bot

Tags: javascript, request, exe, lost-focus

Im not sure what I can provide, as Im very new to all of this.

I downloaded a .zip, extracted, got down to the .exe that I was supposed to be able to run. This is a /api/web.aspx script that is supposed to inject into an api. When I launch the .exe I am met with just a white screen of the window, top left readying:
"{"error":"Invalid request"}"

Dont know what to do.

```
 Directory of C:\Users\19517\Downloads\NBot\NBot\Nbot

01/31/2020  11:36 AM    <DIR>          .
01/31/2020  11:36 AM    <DIR>          ..
01/01/2016  02:59 PM           872,384 credits.html
01/01/2016  02:59 PM         4,173,928 d3dcompiler_47.dll
01/01/2016  02:59 PM           987,648 ffmpegsumo.dll
01/01/2016  02:59 PM        10,457,856 icudtl.dat
01/01/2016  02:59 PM            86,016 libEGL.dll
01/01/2016  02:59 PM         1,890,304 libGLESv2.dll
01/01/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          locales
01/01/2016  02:59 PM        64,430,357 NaughtyBot.exe
01/31/2020  11:35 AM                 0 New File
01/01/2016  02:59 PM         7,482,865 nw.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM         6,873,600 nwjc.exe
01/01/2016  02:59 PM        14,879,232 pdf.dll
01/31/2020  11:31 AM         3,372,821 stuff.txt
              12 File(s)    115,507,011 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\19517\Downloads\NBot\NBot\Nbot\locales

01/01/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          .
01/01/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 am.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 ar.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 bg.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 bn.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 ca.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 cs.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 da.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 de.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 el.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 en-GB.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 en-US.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 es-419.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 es.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 et.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 fa.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 fi.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 fil.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 fr.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 gu.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 hi.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 hr.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 hu.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 id.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 it.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 iw.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 ja.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 kn.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 ko.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 lt.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 lv.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 ml.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 mr.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 ms.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 nl.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 no.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 pl.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 pt-BR.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 pt-PT.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 ro.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 ru.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 sk.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 sl.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 sr.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 sv.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 sw.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 ta.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 te.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 th.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 tr.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 uk.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 vi.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 zh-CN.pak
01/01/2016  02:59 PM                15 zh-TW.pak
              53 File(s)            795 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
              65 File(s)    115,507,806 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  191,099,916,288 bytes free
```

Comment: Maybe you can provide the link so that the rest of us can clue into what you are talking about?

Comment: https://www.999dice.com/api/web.aspx

Sorry thought my pictures had this.

Comment: This is the root API to the software I’m supposed to be running. The .exe contains another exe and a zip with what seems like a newer version .js but when opening the .exe I’m given this white page. I decompressed via password. Have tried .7z, windows and others to the same result.

Comment: Maybe the API is buggy?

Comment: I’ve spent 2 days troubleshooting.

Comment: The website will accept requests to the web address above only in POST not Js, they return in Js but I am 100% self taught. I also tried about every fix in the book. I’ve now reset my computer to factory. It may have been bad decompressing but I really don’t know how it could be. If anyone offers support via remote, I’d pay for some real professional at this point. My skills are lack luster.

Comment: If it were bad decompressing, usually it won't decompress at all on checksum errors. Best thing u can do, and really i should have mentioned this earlier, is post your code attempts, and also in your case, the directory structure of the unpacked zip.

Comment: I’ll retry once with a new boot. The structure is rather wacky to be honest and really made no sense. At least of the zip file.

Comment: But then again it could be perfectly normal for an application pushing Js and http, etc. found it odd it had a zip inside the exe and then another exe next to it. Super confused and I bet there’s a very normal explanation but to me.... its Chinese sometimes.

Comment: Not sure why there is an `.exe` file at all. But perhaps you could post a `dir /s` of the folder structure. You can save the directory structure to a text file like so `dir /s >textfile.txt`. Then edit it down to the relevant parts.

Comment: I’m running a windows 10 home 64bit. The vendor of said application has confirmed its working and fully functional. I had reached out to the website for further clarification on error 400 for their api aspx waiting to hear back.

Comment: Well the exe is an application that has its own UI away from the website itself.

Comment: I’m jumping on now. Thank you for all the help. I’ll post it before I even try so I can get a best case first try. It’s a zip folder , > folder > 4 zip folders > 2 of which are videos etc, other two are 32bit and 64 hit application exe houses for said software. I’ll post it but just to give you an idea.